# ios 5 screen initial auto rotation

Tags: xcode, ios5, autorotate

I know that since ios 6 has been released, Apple has changed all of the functions that set the auto rotation of the screen. I have been able to apply these changes but ever since I have begun using the latest xcode version all of my apps will not auto rotate automatically to an orientation when they are launched in ios 5. What I understand is that in order to support the auto rotation from ios 5 you just keep the functions that conducted the auto rotation and I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    BOOL allowed = NO;
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    allowed = YES;
    }
    return allowed;
}
```

My problem is that when the app launches in the simulator it automatically displays in the portrait orientation but when I rotate the simulator to landscape left it auto rotates and then does not auto rotate back. Why doesn't the simulator rotate the app's display to landscape automatically? And will this also occur on devices running ios 5 or 5.1?

EDIT

I also noticed that this problem occurs in the ios 5 and 5.1 simulators but not in the ios 4.3 simulator

Comment: Make sure that the supported orientations are only landscape, as the simulator will check those values when it launches.

Comment: Thank you!!! I forgot to do that and now it works

Comment: Great! I'll post my comment as an answer for future people to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the supported orientations are only landscape, as the simulator will check those values when it launches. This can be found in the **Project->Summary** tab in **Xcode**, or you can edit it directly in you **info.plist** file. Hope that Helps!